# Get device type (phone/tablet/other) by brand name

Tags: api

I have a long list of devices names and manufacturers that I got from various sources. I am searching for a programmatic way (probably api) to determine which of the devices are phones, which are tablets and which are something else (a computer for example).

I searched the web and I could only find the [WURFL](http://www.scientiamobile.com) API which is pretty good, but it is not able to determine a device only by its name.

Some examples of devices (name, manufactures):

Galaxy Note 3, Samsung

MID-97D, Netbook

Thanks for the help!

**Edit**:

All the answers were very good. If I could split the bounty I would have done that.

I chose to give the bounty for the GSMArena answer because it was the most useful and practical one.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is GSMArena maybe helpful? 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660151/Screen-scraping-using-YQL-and-AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and googling for a while, I came across a site called [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/). Now the site is a comparison site for phones and tablets, you can basically see all specs of a tablet/phone. Looking at the source code of the search page I found that there was a div with the class "maker" that contained all the search results.

Also once you click on a phone/tablet link it takes you to a page with the title "tablet name - Full tablet specs" if its a tab, and "mobile name - Full phone specs" if it's a mobile.

If it found a direct match to a search query it redirected straight to the spec page, so i added a If test to check if it is the search page or spec page.

My program gets the first link in the "maker" div (using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)) and then goes to the link, pulls out html, and then gets the title of the page.

If no results are found, my program marks it as "Others"

Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
searchlist = ["galaxy note","nexus 10","nexus 5","galaxy ace","moto g","galaxy tab 2", "MID-97D"]
for searchstr in searchlist:
    other = False
    searchstr = searchstr.replace(" ", "%20")
    searchlink = "http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName="+searchstr
    string = urllib.request.urlopen(searchlink).read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(string,"lxml")
    if soup.title.string == "Phone Finder results - GSMArena.com":
        makerdiv = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'makers'})
        links = makerdiv[0].find_all('a')
        if len(links) != 0:
            link = "http://www.gsmarena.com/" + links[0].attrs['href']
            string = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(string,"lxml")
        else:
            other = True
    if other == False:
        title = soup.title.string
        name = title.split("-")[0]
        rest = title.split("-")[1]
        taborphone = rest.split(" ")[2]
    else:
        name = searchstr
        taborphone = "other"
    print("Name:",name)
    print("Type:",taborphone)
```

Output:

```
Name: Samsung Galaxy Note5 
Type: phone
Name: Samsung Google Nexus 10 P8110 
Type: tablet
Name: LG Nexus 5X 
Type: phone
Name: Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 
Type: phone
Name: Motorola Moto G (3rd gen) 
Type: phone
Name: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 P3100 
Type: tablet
Name: MID-97D
Type: other
```

And it works :)

Pros:

The database will always stay updated, and GSMArena has lots of phones and tablets in its database

Cons:

It cant be used for devices other than tablet and mobiles, like netbooks  etc.

I just noticed that @Oli has suggested GSMArena in the comments.

Comment: I already thought about it but didn't have the time to investigate the site. Very useful, Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! So is this the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Probably yes, but the other answers (especially @Benjamin Gruenbaum's one) are also very good. I am not sure yet who shall I give the bounty to.

Comment: The whole point of the question was a way to categorize devices, and as you pointed out, even though the FCC was a brilliant idea, it couldn't tell you what type of device it is...

Answer (score 7):

I suggest a simpler approach. Whenever a device is used for wireless communication it has to be certified. In the US - that's the FCC.

They have an API:

```
https://data.fcc.gov:443/api/accessibilityclearinghouse/product/searchProducts?api_key=23232323&format=json&rowPerPage=20&searchString=galaxy%20s4
```

This gladly returns:

> ```
>   "maker": "Samsung",
> ```

See it here: https://ach.fcc.gov/for-developers//#!/API/product_searchProducts_get

You can also query apis like eBay and Amazon.

Comment: FCC provides an interesting API, however FCC API does not seem to return any results for provided examples of search queries, so you need exact name of the device to get results. Also even if API returns results for some queries, type of the device is always 'Mobile', so it is impossible to say if it is a tablet or a phone. The question was how to identify device type, not maker.

Comment: This api seems to be pretty good although when I searched for example "Nexus 7" I didn't find any results. So it seems to be not full, yet pretty useful. Also, I would glad to hear about the other APIs you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am using http://www.handsetdetection.com/ API paid version, which gives accurate results. They have free trail version option for testing.

```
$referer_site = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //"NokiaN95";//
$curlOpts = array(
CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.handsetdetection.com/apiv3/site/detect/xxxxx.json",     
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,    
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_DIGEST, 
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type:application/json'),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"user-agent":"'.$useragent.'"}');
/******************************************/

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlOpts);
$responseBody = curl_exec($curl);
$jsonObj = json_decode($responseBody);
curl_close($curl);


$device_details = json_decode($responseBody);
```

Comment: This is a neater solution than the accepted answer. The Free tier allows for 20000 hits a month.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach should work, but will require some programming:

1. Create groups of synonyms for each device type name you are trying to categorize (e.g. [phone; cellphone], [tablet; pad])
2. Use [Google Search REST API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) to get search results for your device name (more specialized, internet retailers API can be used instead)
3. Use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to count the number of matches in search results against each synonym in a particular group
4. Group with highest total match count for all synonyms represents your device type
5. If no matches found, device type should be classified as 'other'. To prevent false positive matching as one of target groups, minimum number of matches can be set to be sure that 'other' device is not put to 'tablets' or 'phones' by mistake. I assume that regexp check will be performed against multiple search result items at once

The main pros are that your results will be always up-to-date and supported by the best search engine in the world.

As for cons, if you will use Google API for free they will limit allowed number of requests per day (can be increased for fee). Also some moderation may be required for 'other' devices to make sure your classification program works correctly

The approach potential can roughly be estimated before development by just entering sample device names in google and looking at search results. If they contain 'missing' device types, then it is worth trying to implement this.

Since Google API has strict rate limits and restrictions for commercial use, you may consider using other search engines instead, e.g. Yahoo, which [allows commercial use](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html) if you notify them and they have high rate limits in this case.

Comment: Already tried that, but google policies do not allow to use their services for not real search queries made by end users. They have actually temporary banned me once I tried to use their services programmatically.

Comment: You may consider using other search engines instead, e.g. Yahoo, which allows commercial use if you notify them and they have high rate limits in this case, see https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html

Answer (score -1):

I usually use mobile device API https://specsapi.cc.
Here is the cURL example:

```
curl -X GET “https://specsapi.cc/specification?limit=1&name=iphone%20xs%20max&year=2018” -H “accept: application/json”
```

They have several ready to use API client https://github.com/specsapi/specsapi-clients